# Why does web root give a 404 in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 site where I changed the routes in the Home controller to remove the Home portion.

My Home Controller looks like

```
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home";
        ViewBag.Current = "Home";

        return View();
    }
```

This works great when I go to http://localhost:29033/Index but when I go to http://localhost:29033 I get the following error:

A public action method 'Index' was not found on controller 'MyProject.Controllers.HomeController'.

My RegisterRoutes looks like:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using `[Route("Index")]`?

Comment: Yeah, I want the page to by www.myurl.com/Index instead of www.myurl.com/home/index. I personally don't care, but the users do for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it appears that attribute routing is being employed here I believe you need to update your routes to get the desired behavior

```
[RoutePrefix("home")]
public class HomeController : Controller {

    [Route("Index")] // Matches GET home/index
    [Route("~/", Name = "root")] //Matches GET /
    public ActionResult Index() {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }    

}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.